# nested attributes change value before save with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I have a **project** model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   has_many  :site_visits, inverse_of: :project, dependent: :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :site_visits, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

   before_save: :convert_site_visit_dates

   def convert_site_visit_dates
     begin
       if self.site_visits_attributes.present?
         self.site_visits_attributes.each do |site_visit|
            site_visit[1]['visit_date'] = convert_date(site_visit[1]['visit_date']) if site_visit[1]['visit_date'].present?
            site_visit[1]['_destroy'] = true if site_visit[1]['_destroy'] == "1"
         end
       end
     rescue StandardError
       nil
     end
   end 

end
```

I have **site_visit** model: (columns - `visit_date`)

```
class SiteVisit < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to  :project

end
```

Before saving the **site_visits** in any particular project through [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) I need to change the value of the `site_visits_attributes` using a callback. In my project model you can see I've defined a callback to change the `visit_date` column of `site_visit` table. But the value is not changing. Thus, in the database null values are being saved.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing: you are manipulating what seems like the attributes hash in a model??? So either you manipulate the attributes hash, and do it in the controller, either you add a callback on the model and fix the model. Not sure why you want to change the `_destroy` flag? That should just work. What I see: You are trying to fix the received date-format, and this should best be done in the controller (or even better: the view --make sure the date are sent to the controller in the correct/expected format?)

Comment: @nathanvda, I did the changes in a helper. So, the issue is resolved. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`site_visits_attributes` is not a method on the Project object.  If you remove `rescue StandardError` you'll catch this issue.

It is probably a better idea to modify the data in a `before_filter` in your controller.  Or alternatively, you could modify the data on `before_save` on the SiteVisit objects.

Comment: I've tried with `before_save` in SiteVisit object. It is not working. I don't want to do that in controller.